# Get Blender scripts path

Tags: python, scripting, path

Is there a clean way to get the absolute path to the `scripts` folder for the currently running version of Blender?

The following code works (on Windows) but it feels a bit hackish.

```
from os.path import dirname, join, normpath
from bpy.app import binary_path_python
normpath(join(dirname(binary_path_python), '..', '..', 'scripts'))
```

Results in `C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.77\\python\\scripts`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a few nice helper methods hidden in the bpy.utils module space. For instance, calling

```
bpy.utils.script_paths()
```

will return all current Blender paths where Python modules can be put. Even if you (like I do on my system) redirect the Scripts Folder to a custom location, so they stay around when updating Blender, using this method you'll get a valid pointer. See this output here:

[image: scripts path]

But you could also use

```
x = bpy.utils.script_path_user()
```

to retrieve the current location of your user scripts. This will return a string, and as a fallback your scripts home directory if no custom path was set.

Comment: Works perfectly. This let me find the [bpy.utils API docs](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.utils.html#bpy.utils.script_paths). Thanks!